# how to reduce loading time in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have one small react app which is based on https://redq.gitbooks.io/isomorphic/content/ theme. The issue is when i built the package it generates main.js with 3MB of size with other smaller chunks.

Below is package.json. Please help me in this regard. Thanks in advance. Let me know if anyone needs any other thing.

```
    {
      "name": "isomorphic",
      "version": "2.9.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "antd": "^3.10.1",    
        "axios": "^0.18.0",    
        "clone": "^2.1.1",
        "fingerprintjs": "^0.5.3",
        "history": "^4.6.3",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",    
        "nprogress": "^0.2.0",    
        "qs": "^6.5.2",
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-async-script-loader": "^0.3.0",        
        "react-confirm-alert": "^2.0.6",
        "react-datepicker": "^1.7.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
        "react-grid-system": "^4.3.1",
        "react-intl": "^2.7.1",
        "react-placeholder": "^2.0.0",
        "react-recaptcha": "^2.3.10",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
        "react-responsive": "^5.0.0",    
        "react-router-dom": "^4.1.0",
        "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.8",
        "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
        "react-select": "^2.1.0",    
        "react-smooth-scrollbar": "^8.0.6",
        "react-throttle": "^0.3.0",
        "react-window-size-listener": "^1.0.10",
        "redux": "^3.7.2",
        "redux-saga": "^0.16.2",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
        "smooth-scrollbar": "^8.2.5",
        "styled-components": "^2.2.1",
        "styled-theme": "^0.3.3"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "react-app-rewired": "^1.4.0",
        "redux-devtools": "^3.3.2",
        "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.1",
        "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.2.0"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-app-rewired start",
        "build": "react-app-rewired build",
        "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Do you really need all these dependencies? Reduce dependencies count = faster build/startup time

Comment: you are using 'redux-saga` and `redux-thunk` both, which basically serves the same purpose.

Comment: Do you want to reduce loading time? or the package size?